# graphql .NET endpoint name

Tags: graphql, apollo-server, graphql.net

**We are using graphql .net (Apollo Server)**

Is the a way to change the URL endpoint?

So from

http://localhost:xxx/graphql

I want it to be

http://localhost:xxx/newEndpoint

Comment: Are you using GraphQL.NET on the server or the client? I guess this question is all about Apollo really? Which means you should just read the docs... https://www.apollographql.com/docs/apollo-server/v1/setup/

Comment: I meant apollo server, editing the question

Comment: So there's no need to mention .NET at all, and my link above still stands - read the docs!

Answer (score 0):

OK i just figured it out, it's pretty simple.

On the server side all you have to do it state the endpoint you desire when configuring the server.

`app.UseGraphQL<YourSchema>("/yourNewEndPoint");`

on the client side you also need to modify the uri you are passing to httpLink

```
    const http = httpLink.create({
        uri: 'http://localhost:port/yourNewEndPoint'
    });
```